# Pulls & Multiplying Multiple Data Points Based on Year Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Having an issue figuring out a proper Google sheets formula that works

This is my [reference sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xKuFt0hozc0snXW_rSkbuDtd18fn2cvObdnztaZNldg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=SUM(IF(AND('Online Arbitrage'!A:A = D5, 'Online Arbitrage'!M:M >=DATE(A2,1,1), 'Online Arbitrage'!M:M <=DATE(A2,12,31), 'Online Arbitrage'!N:N> 0),'Online Arbitrage'!H:H*'Online Arbitrage'!N:N))
```

I tried this formula in the "Taxes" worksheet and other variants with no success.

I am needing it to pull through the total purchases per supplier from the "Online Arbitrage" sheet based on the year that I have entered into A2.

In this example, I am expecting a result of $2,696.04 and it is producing a result of $0. I've tried other variations of this formula and it produced a result of around $5,700 which was also incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=sumproduct(('Online Arbitrage'!$A$4:$A=D5)*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$4:$M>=DATE(A2,1,1))*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$4:$M<=DATE(A2,12,31))*('Online Arbitrage'!$N$4:$N>0)*'Online Arbitrage'!$H$4:$H*'Online Arbitrage'!$N$4:$N)
```

You generally can't use AND/OR statements in arrays as they aggregate so won't give you the expected result. Instead, use * instead of AND and + instead of OR. I've also limited your ranges to avoid the header cells.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you.

I am attempting to figure out a similar formula adding one additional criteria to the one you provided, adding 'Online Arbitrage'!U:U,"Exempt

Any ideas on how I can incorporate this with your formula or should I make a new thread?

Comment: You should technically ask a new question... but just try adding *('Online Arbitrage'!$U$4:$U="Exempt") to the end of the calculations within the SUMPRODUCT.