# How to add additional criteria to sumproduct formula

Tags: google-sheets

I apologize in advance, when it comes to things like formulas, I have very little knowledge.

I have attempted to refine my formula for many hours with ChatGPT with no luck so far.

I had previously asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255264/pulls-multiplying-multiple-data-points-based-on-year-criteria) & was able to find a solution to my formula.

This is the current working formula that a kind member provided to me in my previous question:

```
=sumproduct(('Online Arbitrage'!$A$10:$A=D8)*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$10:$M>=DATE(A5,1,1))*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$10:$M<=DATE(A5,12,31))*('Online Arbitrage'!$N$10:$N>0)*'Online Arbitrage'!$H$10:$H*'Online Arbitrage'!$N$10:$N)
```

I have an additional column that I would like to pull similar data for but with one additional criteria:

```
('Online Arbitrage'!$U$10:$U="Exempt")
```

My hope is that it will calculate all of the same data from the previous formula but only pull through the items with the "Exempt" label in column U (for total tax exempt purchase).

I have attempted to add this additional criteria all over the working formula with no success.

Does anyone know how I can add this additional criteria into this formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=sumproduct(('Online Arbitrage'!$A$10:$A=D8)*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$10:$M>=DATE(A5,1,1))*('Online Arbitrage'!$M$10:$M<=DATE(A5,12,31))*('Online Arbitrage'!$N$10:$N>0)*'Online Arbitrage'!$H$10:$H*'Online Arbitrage'!$N$10:$N*('Online Arbitrage'!$U$10:$U="Exempt"))`